# How well were medieval lords and ladies acquainted with the culture of their subjects?

Tags: medieval, culture

In my world, there a few traditions and celebrations the common folk do. During the winter, they give their loved one (can be family but usually romantic love) a stone with a fire rune on it. Men make their wives  little ornaments to bring them luck. Men or women with mages as their partners have their clothes sewn with runes on them in times of war. How much would a medieval lord understand the culture assuming they have been in power for generations? Not like a recently conquered  area with a new family or person in power.

Comment: Is there a metric or guide to discern good answers from bad answers?

Comment: Are the lords and trier subjects coming from the same ethnic background?

Comment: Are you asking about real life? We have a [history.se] site.

Comment: VTC:Too Story-Based. This falls into my class of questions, "how many angels can dance on the head of a pin? Answer: as many as wanting" because you, the author, can simply decide how much insight the nobility has. Unless what you're really asking is, "To better improve the design of my world, could someone explain how well nobility in France would understand the traditions of commoners circa 1300 A.D.?" If it's something like that, you need to be specific about the location (down to the city/town, if possible) and year or the question can't be answered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It really depends on your culture and the lord/lady's social standing.

If your lords mainly reside on their own lands, next to the common folk, they will know the customs and speak their language. However, if they live in the capital (like Japanese daimyo were required to do) they will have their own subculture, often different from the commoners. Sometimes differences can be so big that the nobility and commoners do not wear the same clothing styles and speak the same language. It was the case in the 18th-early 19th century Russia[*] (not the Middle Ages, but it is still very much telling).

There is also a possibility that if your country comprises many different ethnicities, your lords may come from one and commoners from another. That was the case in some regions of China at different historical points.

Social standing also would affect familiarity with traditions. Minor nobility in the Middle Ages would not be very different from the commoners and would share their customs and rituals. High lords and ladies would probably live where the court is and move with the court, as was customary at that time. So, they would have their own subculture. The court may move a lot and do not get acquainted with local customs at all. How much the court moves and how far depends on the country and historical period.

The size of the country also plays a role. Small isolated kingdoms are less likely to create elaborate courts with the nobility that never sees or deals with commoners. Big empires always end up with aristocracy that knows very little about local traditions and creates its own customs.

In short, **your lords and ladies can know about local customs and traditions as much as you need them to know.** Just make sure that the rest of your society is set up to accommodate this.

---

[*] Russian and French language status in the Russian Empire of the late 18th-early 19th century was complicated. Not all, even ethnically Russian nobles, were proficient in Russian. It does not mean that they could not speak any Russian at all. Most of them could manage some Russian. But polite talk in salons and written conversations would be conducted in French (or German). There were, of course, nobles who were proficient in both Russian and French. There were writers who wrote in Russian almost exclusively (they were still fluent in French and other required at that time languages). Russian was also the language of official government communication. But French was the language used by the universities to teach for example physics and geography.

Russian literature and academic discussion of that time were full of debates related to the purity of the Russian language, which borrowed a lot of words from German and French since Peter I. The proponents of Russian were lamenting over the disconnect between nobility and common folk due to the use of different languages in everyday conversations.

This is a fascinating topic, but I am not sure how useful it is for your world, so. I'll just stop here :)

Comment: 18th century Russian nobles spoke Russian just like Russian commoners. *Some* of them were better educated and also spoke French, or German. Some could read Church Slavonic. But they all spoke Russian, at least those who were actually Russians. (Yes, some commoners didn't speak Russian, because they were not Russians. But then some aristocrats didn't speak good Russian because they were not Russians. The Russian empire was large.)

Comment: @AlexP Not all historical accounts agree with you on this. [This book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/french-and-russian-in-imperial-russia/4C62EB534DD5C24C5D275230961D0173) goes into greater detail. Decembrists (1820s) were also well-known for their lack of proficiency in Russian. [Bestuzhev-Ryumin](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mikhail_Bestuzhev-Ryumin), for example, demanded that all communication with investigators and the court was done in French.

Comment: OTOH, moving with the court would not prevent your knowing customs that were widely practiced, so much depends on how "local" we are talking about.

Comment: Even your source says that he *"was known to dress in the clothes of lower classes and agitate people to revolt against the monarchy"*... which he obviously didn't do in French.

Comment: Russia is in no way special. In the late 18th and throughout the 19th centuries *everybody* who was somebody in Europe knew some French, at least enough to read and to chatter. Russia, Romania, Germany, doesn't matter; even in Italy. French was *the* international language of the time, and *the* language of higher culture, just how we use English today, or how they had used Latin in western Europe up to the end of the 17th century. But in no country did French acquire even the shadow of an official role, and it remained a foreign language everywhere -- just like English today.

Comment: There are numerous indications that, while Bestuzhev-Ryumin was not a prolific writer, he had full mastery of Russian language; he was a co-author of Decembrists' "catechism". IMHO his request to conduct investigation in French was only to frustrate and delay the process.

Comment: @Mary I agree. I would also add that a lot depends on the court size and traditions as well.

Comment: @AlexP You are misinterpreting my words. I've never stated that French was an official language. I specifically mentioned that Russian was the official language. English today is nowhere close to what French was in Russia in the 18th century. For one, no one says that English is better suited for expressing one's feelings and emotions. That was the case in Russia. English is also not used in everyday conversations among household members unless it is their native language. French was used like that. I am not saying that Russian nobility did not speak Russian at all. They did to varying degrees

Comment: @AlexP But there is evidence suggesting that French was preferred language at that time in high society circles. Russian was the preferred language for commoners in the ethnically Russian areas. This is the difference I am talking about. Nothing else.

Comment: @Alexander If Bestuzhev-Ryumin was a co-author it does not mean that he had full mastery of Russian. They could've discussed it in Chinese or some alien language and then just wrote it all down in Russian. I am sure that  Bestuzhev-Ryumin had at least some working knowledge of Russian, but I full mastery is something that is hard to assess without sources. Again, I am not suggesting that nobility of that time had no knowledge of Russian at all. This is about preferences and cultural differences.

Comment: @Otkin we may speculate about how the co-authorship work, but "[Данные о политическом обществе](http://az.lib.ru/b/bestuzhewrjumin_m_p/text_0020.shtml)" was written by Bestuzhev-Ryumin himself. My point is that it would be very uncommon for Russian noble (who actually grew up in Russia) to be anything less than fluent in Russian.

Comment: @Alexander I admit that I am not familiar enough with this topic, so I will accept your argument. However, lack of fluency was not my point. Language preference was my point. It does not matter how many languages you are fluent at, what matters is which language you use in which situation. French was the language of choice for polite conversation, personal correspondence, and formal education.

Comment: FWIW, Prussian King Frederick the Great's written and spoken German is often said to have been much worse than his French. He was well able to have conversations with the lower classes in German, but in contexts that required more sophistication, he seems to have preferred French.

Comment: @Otkin not really relevant, but just to make the record straight - in 18th century predominant language in higher education was Latin. In 1768, Russia started to shift to native Russian (however, Bestuzhev-Ryumin didn't have a formal education).

Comment: @Mary, nobles easily could have let-them-eat-cake level of ignorance of the culture of the commoners, even if it's as widely practiced as eating bread.

Comment: That particular anecdote came not from the medieval era, but from an ancien regime culture particularly filled with nobles NOT being on their estates but dancing attendance on the king.

Answer (score 6):

Thoroughly if it's anything like medieval Europe.  As in, those would be things that people did, not things that commoners did.

Nobility and commoners routinely associated in medieval times.  A noble household would have everyone, from the lord down to the meanest servants, eat at the same table, with common entertainments to follow.  May Kings would call on nobles -- we know because noble account books recount payments to them.

Comment: The gap between classes increased after the Middle Ages, and there is a tendency to assume that the "Upstairs, Downstairs" separation was always there.

Answer (score -1):

In short answer not well. Until   Fairly recently  if you are an aristocrat you are more likely to relate culturally  to another aristocrat from  a foreign country then to the culture of your own peasants.  What they did have in common was often because of large institutions that imposed unifying norms, values and  tradditional (Catholic Church is a perfect example)  Even then there was still a large cultural divide between the classes.

Comment: The question does not ask whether aristocrats related culturally to the commoners over whom they ruled; the question asks whether the aristocats were acquainted with the culture of the commoners. And the answer is that at least in the classical Antiquity and in the European Middle Ages, yes, they were.